# When is it appropriate to use the HTML Coded Character Set?

Tags: html, character-encoding, escaping

I would like to know when you should represent a particular character as its coded character in HTML, i.e. when (and WHY) should you use `&#36;` instead of `'$'` ?

Here is the list I am looking at:

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Comment: You are referring to HTML 2.0, which is really antique now, and your question is really about using character references (or entity references), or “HTML escapes” for characters as they might be informally called – a question that has been asked many times here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you use space. Other times you'll need to use > or <